# Python sum up a set of array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sum

The objective of task required to produce an array output such that `output[i]` is equal to the sum of all the elements of nums except `nums[i]`.

Eg: given `[6,7,8,9]`, return `[24,23,22,21]`.

`Input = [6,7,8,9]`

The calculation behind is

```
0+7+8+9 = 24
6+0+8+9 = 23
6+7+0+9 = 22
6+7+8+0 = 21

Output = [ 24, 24, 22, 21 ]
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck. DO NOT post questions soliciting direct answers for homework problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension:

```
In [1]: a = [6,7,8,9]

In [2]: s = sum(a)

In [3]: [s - i for i in a]
Out[3]: [24, 23, 22, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` broadcasting + vectorised operations for this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([6,7,8,9])

y = np.sum(x) - x

# array([24, 23, 22, 21])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and python's inbuilt sum function

```
 a = [6,7,8,9] #your input array
 b = [] # initialise an empty list
 for index in range(len(a)): #iterate through the list's length
     b.append( sum( a[0:index] + a[index+1:] ) ) #add to two parts before and 
     # after the index
 print(b)
```